# Implementing swipes left/right in ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview, ontouchlistener

I would like to add swipe functionality (rigth to left and left to right) to a ScrollView, but without intercepting all touch events, so that child button would still be clickable.

I added touch listener to the scroll view like this:

```
this.getView().findViewById(R.id.scrollView1).setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener() {
            public void onSwipeTop() {
                Toast.makeText(DetailFragment.this.getActivity(), "top", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            public void onSwipeRight() {
                Toast.makeText(DetailFragment.this.getActivity(), "right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            public void onSwipeLeft() {
                Toast.makeText(DetailFragment.this.getActivity(), "left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            public void onSwipeBottom() {
                Toast.makeText(DetailFragment.this.getActivity(), "bottom", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

If I let it like it is, then my touch listener is never called. So I had to subclass `ScrollView` and override `onInterceptTouchEvent`, so that scroll view will decide which touch events it want to intercept:

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    boolean intercept = false;
    final int action = ev.getAction();
    ViewConfiguration vc = ViewConfiguration.get(this.getContext());
    int slop = vc.getScaledTouchSlop();
    switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            float currX = ev.getX();
            if (Math.abs(currX - originalX) > slop) {
                intercept = true;
            }
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            originalX = ev.getX();
            break;
        }
    }

    return (super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev) || intercept);
}
```

So my idea is to intercept only swipes left/right and all other events should be left to children views. The buttons inside scroll view seem to work, but my listener is never called anyway.

My view in xml looks like this:

```
<com.damluar.mobile.inbox.MyScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:id="@+id/detailLayout">
        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/detailButtonLayout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:background="@color/default_color">
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</com.damluar.mobile.inbox.MyScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check this and mark it if useful.
I have updated the OnSwipeTouchListener a bit to get a callback for onTouch also.

```
public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
private final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(
        new GestureListener());

@Override
public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);

}

private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 50;
    private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 50;
    private static final int SWIPE_DISTANCE = 50;


    private boolean isFlingCall = false;

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        isFlingCall = false;
        return true;
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e){    
        if(!isFlingCall) {
            onTouch();
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {
        try {
            float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
            float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
            if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD
                        && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffX > SWIPE_DISTANCE) {
                        isFlingCall = true;
                        onSwipeRight();
                        return true;
                    }
                    else {
                        onSwipeLeft();
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        onTouch();
        return true;
    }
}

public void onSwipeRight() {
}

public void onSwipeLeft() {
}
public void onTouch() {
}
}
```

Thanks

JRH

Comment: As I wrote, my touch listener is never called. So your listener is not better in this way.